# How to change the color in the element p-colorPicker writing the hexcode (angular)

Tags: angular, hex, angular-reactive-forms, primeng, color-picker

I'm using Angular and I need to find a way to change the color in the element p-colorPicker of PrimeNG writing the hexcode. What I did so far was making the inverse process, the input element text can change
according to the p-colorPicker, but I can't find a way to make the p-colorPicker element change when I write the hexcode in the input element.

```
<p-colorPicker #picker
    id="color"
    name="color"
    formControlName="color"
    format="hex"
    (onChange)="trocarHex()">
</p-colorPicker>
<div class="input-group w-25 mx-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="hexcode">#</span>
    </div>
    <input #hex
        [value]="hexcode"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="hexcode"
        aria-label="hexcode"
        aria-describedby="hexcode"
        maxlength="6" />
</div>
```

```
hexcode: string;

 trocarHex(): void {
   this.hexcode = this.editForm.get(['color'])!.value.slice(1);
}
```

First, I tried to make both have the same "name" of the reactive form, to see if they change one another, but it did not work, then, I'm trying to make just they "talk" to eache other with the changes with only the p-pickColor having the "name" of the property of the reactive form.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are asking for is for the ability to detect changes on the input element and set the hexcode value. If that is the case Angular reactive forms expose an observable stream on the forms so that can be done as following:

First set up two way data bidning to value property:

```
<input #hex
        [(value)]="hexcode"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="hexcode"
        aria-label="hexcode"
        aria-describedby="hexcode"
        maxlength="6" />
```

Then you could do

```
this.editForm.get('color').valueChanges.pipe(debounce(300)).subscribe((value) => this.hexacode = value)
```

You could also try wiring it up to the form. You would have to also use `formGroupName` on parent element, but this should work. I haven't tested it though.
<input #hex
[(value)]=formEdits.get('color').value
formControlName='color'
class="form-control"
placeholder="hexcode"
aria-label="hexcode"
aria-describedby="hexcode"
maxlength="6" />